# How can I structure variables more efficiently in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, variables, if-statement

Sorry if the title is not so specific. I am looking to restructure variables and if-statements in a program to make the code more efficient. The current code is pretty large and I am sure it can be shortened by at least 70%.

I just started learning Python two weeks ago, I may be missing basic functions that are pretty obvious.

Here is the code:

```
def function():

    variable = int(input('Input: ')

    if variable == 10:
        variable = 1
    elif variable == 9:
        variable = 0.9
```

If I want to repeat this with different values and variables it gets pretty long, and this is what I want to fix.

A friend told me to use dictionaries to store the values but I am not sure how to use if-statements with dictionary values.

How should I structure my code to make it shorter?

Comment: What is the goal here? Do you want to divide the input by 10?

Comment: The values in the post are just placeholders, I'm using fixed values for each input value.

Comment: What prompted you to write that `if-elif` block? Is it only because you were not aware of existence of division?

Answer (score -1):

At least for the 10 and 9, you are dividing variable by 10. So its better to write it that way instead of writing it explicitly. Also, you can combine the 2 cases in one if case then.

This will shorten the code a bit.

```
def function():
    variable = int(input('Input: '))
    if variable == 10 || variable == 9:
        variable /= 10
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to include some description on how this answer help to solve the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

If you want to implement a lookup logic clearly, use **dict** structure to save key/value pairs.

The key usually be a string, and value can be any others type, like string, integer, etc.

In your case, you can setup the lookup_table={"10":1,"9":0.9},
and get the value by a key, for example, variable = lookup_table[str(10)]

```
lookup_table={"variable":"value1","variable2":2}
variable = lookup_table[variable]
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to include some description on how this answer help to solve the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Thank you all for your answers, the solution was easier than I expected and now I feel dumb for not knowing before.

```
def probeNew():
    variable = int(input('Input: '))
    output = variable/6.666667
    print(output)

probeNew()
```

Instead of writing all of the fixed values for each input, I just make a formula for whatever result I want from the input. (I know, extremely obvious and easy)

Comment: Good for you, but this is not what you have described in your question and also this function does not do what your example does. For example, your old `function()` would return 7 if this was inputted while your new function will return 0.7. It is a surprising answer to a confusing question.